# Can anyone help me figure out the meaning of this php error message?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827706/can-anyone-help-me-figure-out-what-is-wrong-with-this-code)

Here is my code

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '');

if (!$con) {
    die('Cannot make a connection');
}


mysql_select_db('yumbox_table', $con) or die('Cannot make a connection');    
isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['user_type']);

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                       FROM users 
                      WHERE user_name == ($_POST['user_name']) 
                        AND ($_POST['password']) 
                        AND ($_POST['user_type'])") or die(mysql_error());

$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
$count = mysql_numrows($data);

if ($count == 1) {
    echo("Success!!");
} else {
    echo("BIG FRIGGIN FAILURE!!");
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Whenever I run this code, I receive the following message:

Comment: what error message, post it here

Comment: Maybe he means he gets a blank page. Does he have error displaying turned on?

Comment: please read about SQL INJECTION
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Why don't you assign that `isset()` check to a variable to test?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the query is doing `... WHERE username = $_POST['username'] AND $_POST['password'] AND $_POST['usertype']`. That doesn't make a lot of sense. And, yes, your code is a gaping hole waiting for a hacker.

Comment: @prodigitalson: It goes [further back than that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813436/does-anyone-know-the-meaning-behind-this-php-error-message).  The OP wants us to do it all for them.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: yet strangely... none of them have answers marked ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['user_type'])){
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * from users 
             where user_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name'])."' and 
                   password  = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."' and 
                   user_type = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_type'])."' ");

    if(mysql_numrows($data) == 1) {
       $info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
       echo("Success!!");
    } else {
       echo("BIG FRIGGIN FAILURE!!");
    }
}
else{
   echo "Required Data Missing";
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Be sure to use `mysql_real_escape_string` to clean inserted values. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the error for more details. But a few things I noticed was

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from users where user_name == ($_POST['user_name']) and ($_POST['password']) and ($_POST['user_type'])")
```

You need to change this to

```
//do escaping here. See note below.
$username = isset($_POST['user_name']) ? mysql_real_escape($_POST['user_name']) : '';
$pass     = isset($_POST['password']) ? mysql_real_escape($_POST['password']) : '';
$type     = isset($_POST['user_type']) ? mysql_real_escape($_POST['user_type']) : '';

mysql_query("SELECT * from users where user_name = '{$username}' AND password = '{$pass}' AND user_type = '{$type}'")
```

You need to escape values

MySQL comparisons are `=` and not `==` (thanks for pointing that out @jeremysawesome)

You need to check the column against your POST value

You also have an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please at least use [mysql_real_escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Better yet, switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

You need to assign your `isset` check to a variable and check it. Otherwise it's just a waste.

Comment: Also - I believe the double `==` should be a single `=` for SQL comparisons.

Comment: @jeremysawesome indeed! updating the answer

Comment: @jeremysawesome noticed a bunch of other stuff when I started reading the question proper

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your POST values before you insert put them into your query. You should escape your POST values before you use them in a database query.

Instead of this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * from users where user_name == ($_POST['user_name']) and ($_POST['password']) and ($_POST['user_type'])"
```

Do this:

```
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$user_type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_type']);
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name == '$user_name' AND password == '$password' AND user_type == '$user_type'");
```

Note that I am assuming your columns in the table are 'user_name', 'password', and 'user_type'.