# Can someone help me find out the meaning behind these errors?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone help me figure out the meaning of this php error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827989/can-anyone-help-me-figure-out-the-meaning-of-this-php-error-message)

Here is the code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '');

if (!$con)
{
    die('Cannot make a connection');
}


mysql_select_db('yumbox_table', $con) or die('Cannot make a connection');

$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$user_type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_type']);



$data = mysql_query("SELECT * from users where user_name == '$user_name' AND password == '$password' user_type == '$user_type'") or die(mysql_error());

$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);

$count = mysql_numrows($data);

if ($count==1)
{
    echo ("Success!!");
}
else 
{
    echo ("BIG FRIGGIN FAILURE!!");
}



mysql_close($con);
```

and these is the error messages generated from said code:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_name in C:\wamp\www\login.php on line 12
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0013  371904  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\login.php on line 13
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0013  371904  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: user_type in C:\wamp\www\login.php on line 14
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0013  371904  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== '' AND password == '' user_type == ''' at line 1
```

Comment: @user717363 stop spamming questions. Please update your original questions and leave feedback on that.

Answer (score 0):

- Some of your variables are not set. They are empty. Therefore the `Undefined index` messages
- Your query is wring also. The comparison operator for strings is `=`, not `==`. It should be `SELECT * from users where user_name = '$user_name' AND password = '$password' AND user_type == '$user_type'"`
- You forgot the `=` before the `user_type` column.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure by the error in this part.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * from users where user_name == '$user_name' AND password == '$password' user_type == '$user_type'") or die(mysql_error());
```

try using this

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * from users where user_name == '".$user_name."' AND password == '".$password."' user_type == '".$user_type."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: edited your question, added code formatting